# Can't run ubuntu as normal

Tags: boot, mount

The problem is something that I absolutely don't understand.[The probelm][1]
I've tried with the advanced mode - recovery mode. Tried to clean, fsck and every other option. After this the system runs BUT! It doesn't run like usual. I don't have the screen light bar in the top left corner, my additional monitor is not working. These are the things that I see in first place. The other problem is that this image above appears on every system restart. Tried to umount the /dev/sdb1. The commands I used are as follow:

```
umount -l /dev/sdb1
umount -f /dev/sdb1
```

I saw this as fix after googling. Well, it wasn't a fix. Not sure what more to provide. I had a USB with Ubuntu in the usb drive when I've started the PC. Could this be the problem somehow ? Begging you for some assistance because I really don't know what to do from now on.
[1]:https://pasteboard.co/JAGSiOw.jpg

Comment: The only details we really have to go off is your screenshot.  Perhaps you can add more details and specifics about what exactly you've tried and the results of those attempts.  This looks to me like a dying hard drive.

Comment: USB plugged in, would only be problem if corrupted and you booted it instead of main system( problems you see are in USB, not your main system).  Would unplug USB and boot your system and use disks smart data to check all drives.  State which drive your Ubuntu is on, sda or sdb